# How viable is it to decat a Lotus Evora?

Tags: catalytic-converter, tuning

The Evora has a secondary decat kit, but no primary decat kit.

How viable is it to fully decat an Evora? The main problem I foresee is tuning. It uses the Toyota 2GR-FE V6 engine. Does this engine have OEM-supported tuning software available?

Comment: I would doubt Toyota has anything available. Most manufacturers don't provide anything like that. [D3 Pro Tuner](https://d3performance.net/index.php/product/tuning-software/) provides some kind of tuning for 2GR-FE engines. HPTuners provides for 1GR-FE V6's, but I don't think that would work for your purposes. Anyways, a little light. Not sure what a "primary" or "secondary" decat kit is supposed to be?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 There are two cats in most US cars, a primary and secondary. A secondary decat just replaces the secondary cat, not the primary.

Comment: That is not my experience. There are two cats for dual banked engines, but they are not primary and secondary to each other (inline or in series). They are both 3-way cats functioning for the cylinder banks they support (in parallel). VERY few manufacturers use a primary/secondary cat system. These are usually used only when a NOx catalyst is separated from the HC/CO catalysts. It is by far cheaper for the manufacturer to have it all included in one cat versus having to deal with two.